# Почему он мне не дает переопределить значение у объекта?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const dataGroupForm: DocumentGroup = {
        ...this.data,
        caption: this.form.value.caption,
        parent_id: Number(this.form.value.parent_id),
        is_default: false,
        description: 'RTI',
    };
    if (dataGroupForm.parent_id === null || 0) {
        dataGroupForm.parent_id: undefined
    }
```

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dataGroupForm.parent_id === null || 0) {
        dataGroupForm.parent_id = undefined
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]